# Is there a way to extract vuforia library from a unity project and use it into a Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to be sure if it's posible to do. Vuforia SDK is able for unity projects but it's comprised as an unity package. After unpackage it into an unity project can I copy the Vuforia folder of the unity project and paste it into Xamarin project and use it?

I know the alternative way is to use vuforia SDK for android then use the .jar file into xamarin project but I think the way I mentioned above would be more direct to use.

Comment: Vuforia is available in Nuget. Not sure if that's the same as the Unity library but I can't image it's any different.

Comment: This package was submitted by waveengine.net and it just provides a camera component for vision based AR.